# Android AppCompat with Toolbar & CM 11 Class cast exception

Tags: android, cyanogenmod, android-appcompat

I have a user running CM 11 and he reported the following stacktrace to me:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$LayoutParams
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.applyInsets(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:172)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:317)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2552)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16521)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1915)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5603)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In my app, I am using the AppCompat themes with a [preferenceActivity similar to this one](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/7200281446186c7192cb02f54dc2b38e02d705e5/sdk/extras/android/support/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java).

For this stacktrace, I am not 100% sure where to start debugging. Anyone encounter this kind of issue in the past know where I should start focusing my efforts?

Comment: On the particular device, yes. I actually think that the issue are the build tools 23.2.0 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be with the support library version 23.2.0.

I had the following in my gradle file:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
```

And when I changed it to the following:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

Things worked fine on cyanogenmod.